# Displaying information within a div element

Tags: javascript, html

I don't know if I am doing this right, but I am trying to display the totals in the table after the script loops  I have been searching on this site for days, but haven't had any luck.  Here is my code:
HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Title</title>
  <script src="script.js" type=J AVASCRIPT></script>
</head>

<body>
  Number of simulations:
  <input type="textbox" id="loops">
  <br>
  <br>
  <input type="button" value="Play" id="play" onClick="simulate()">
  <br>
  <br>
  <table border="Thick">
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>Wins</td>
      <td>Percentage</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Player</td>
      <td>
        <div id="playWins" value="test"></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div id="playPercent"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Computer</td>
      <td>
        <div id="comWins"></div>
        <td>
          <div id="comPercent"></div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Ties</td>
      <td>
        <div id="ties"></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div id="tiesPercent"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Javascript:

```js
    function simulate() {
      var userSelect;
      var comSelect;
      var ties = 0;
      var playWins = 0;
      var comWins = 0;
      var loops;
      var counter = 0;
      loops = document.getElementById("loops").innerHTML;

      while (loops > counter) {
        userSelect = new Math.random();
        if (userSelect < 0.34) {
          userSelect = "rock";
        } else if (userSelect <= 0.67) {
          userSelect = "paper";
        } else {
          userSelect = "scissors";
        }

        comSelect = new Math.random();
        if (comSelect < 0.34) {
          comSelect = "rock";
        } else if (comSelect <= 0.67) {
          comSelect = "paper";
        } else {
          comSelect = "scissors";
        }

        if (userSelect == comSelect) {
          ties = ties + 1;
        } else if (((userSelect = "rock") && (comSelect = "scissors")) || ((userSelect = "paper") && (comSelect = "rock")) || ((userSelect = "scissors") && (comSelect = "paper"))) {
          playWins = playWins + 1;
        } else {
          comWins = comWins + 1;
        }
        counter++;
      }


      //Displaying information in table -- will not work
      document.getElementById("playWins").value = ((playWins).toString());
      document.getElementById("comWins").value = (comWins).toString();
      document.getElementById("ties").value = (ties).toString();
    }
```

Comment: divs don't have a value field.  Try setting the textContent field of the 'playWins', 'comWins', and 'ties' elements.

Comment: `document.getElementById("playWins").value = ((playWins).toString());`... where did you get this code?

Comment: I made it, I know it's probably not right.  Why do you ask?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead to use

```
document.getElementById("playWins").value
```

try with:

```
document.getElementById("playWins").textContent
```

For more details about how to write in a div see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) (do not use innerHTML).

To convert a text to number you can use:

```
+document.getElementById("loops").value.trim()
```

The best way, just to avoid conversion from text to number, to define an input box as numeric is:

```
<input type="number" id="loops">
```

A solution can be:

```js
function simulate() {
  var userSelect;
  var comSelect;
  var ties = 0;
  var playWins = 0;
  var comWins = 0;
  var loops;
  var counter = 0;
  loops = +document.getElementById("loops").value.trim();

  while (loops > counter) {
    userSelect = Math.random();
    if (userSelect < 0.34) {
      userSelect = "rock";
    } else if (userSelect <= 0.67) {
      userSelect = "paper";
    } else {
      userSelect = "scissors";
    }

    comSelect = Math.random();
    if (comSelect < 0.34) {
      comSelect = "rock";
    } else if (comSelect <= 0.67) {
      comSelect = "paper";
    } else {
      comSelect = "scissors";
    }

    if (userSelect == comSelect) {
      ties = ties + 1;
    }
    else if (((userSelect = "rock") && (comSelect = "scissors")) || ((userSelect = "paper") && (comSelect = "rock")) || ((userSelect = "scissors") && (comSelect = "paper"))) {
      playWins = playWins + 1;
    }
    else {
      comWins = comWins + 1;
    }
    counter++;
  }
  //Displaying information in table -- will not work
  document.getElementById("playWins").textContent = playWins.toString();
  document.getElementById("comWins").textContent = comWins.toString();
  document.getElementById("ties").textContent = ties.toString();
}
```

```html
Number of simulations: <input type="textbox" id="loops"><br><br>
<input type="button" value="Play" id="play" onClick="simulate()"><br><br>
<table border="Thick">
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>Wins</td>
        <td>Percentage</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Player</td>
        <td>
            <div id="playWins" value="test"></div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div id="playPercent"></div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Computer</td>
        <td>
            <div id="comWins"></div>
        <td>
            <div id="comPercent"></div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Ties</td>
        <td>
            <div id="ties"></div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div id="tiesPercent"></div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This works, but when I try it in my program, nothing is displayed.  Also, I fixed a logic error in the random selections.

Comment: Yes, I did.  did I maybe not point to the javascript file correctly?

Comment: Substitute the code in your script.js with my Js function

Answer (score 0):

I see an error while getting the loops value. Try this

```
loops = document.getElementById("loops").value;
```

Update based on my comment below:

Consider the following changes

```
userSelect = Math.random(); 
.
.
.
comSelect = Math.random();
```

Also update content value as:

```
document.getElementById("playWins").innerHTML = ...;
```

Comment: You can edit your answer with more information, it would probably be more useful than adding it as comments.

Comment: Thanks @DBS. I'm a newbie. :)

Answer (score 0):

Rather you could try this:
document.getElementById("playWins").innerHTML = "YOUR VALUE";